# Range of any projection is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $P$ a projection.
Show that the range of any projection is a closed subspace.

Can I use the fact that a Banach space is complete and thus closed and that  $P = P^2$ to show that the range of $P$ is in fact closed?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148842/projection-in-hilbert-space-onto-non-closed-subspace?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If the projection is continuous, then the range of $P$ is closed, as it is the kernel of the continuous projection $I-P$.

However not all projections on a Banach space are continuous (as opposed to what happens in the case of a finite dimensional space).
So, in general, this is not true. Take for instance the subspace generated by $\{(1,0,\dots), (0,1,0, \dots), \dots\}$ in $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$. You can then extend the set $\{(1,0,\dots), (0,1,0, \dots), \dots\}$ to a basis of $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ using the Axiom od Choice and then project onto the subspace generated by those elements. As the subspace (which is the range of such projection) has a countable basis, it [can't be Banach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-hamel-basis-of), hence it can't be closed.

Comment: Which projection on that subspace?  There is really no difference between Banach and Hilbert spaces here.  A projection on a non-closed subspace would not be continuous.  But examples of non-continuous linear operators on Banach spaces require the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yeah, indeed you use the axiom of choice to extend that set to a basis of $X$ and then project. And sorry, I meant finite dimensional, my bad.